# I can't ask a question on stackoverflow for the past day

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, google-chrome

When I click `Ask Question`

I get this page

[image: error]

as you can see, no panel for formatting your questions is available, here is a close up of the error on the console

[image]

**BROWSER VERSION**
I am using Google Chrome Version `51.0.2704.103 m`

**EVEN IN INCOGNITO**

[image: incognito mode error]

Comment: Browser version?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome `Version 51.0.2704.103 m`

Comment: I have the same issue. Firefox 47.0

Comment: I'm also using Chrome `Version 51.0.2704.103 m` but I don't have this issue. Can you see if it still happens in incognito mode?

Comment: No repro on Firefox 47.

Comment: @DeepSpace yea, the problem persists even on incognito mode

Comment: I have re-deployed, fixing the "none" issue (second screen), and tweaking the code to force a re-bundle of the js (first screen); can you re-test and let me know if it is any different?

Comment: thank you, that fixed it, no error on the console and the page is rendering normally

Answer (score 11):

That's odd; I'm inclined to think minification, but : I cannot reproduce the issue either logged in or anon; the code here is actually talking to an array (`someArray.push(whatever);`, where `someArray` is initialized to `=[]`), and is never assigned to anything else - so `push` *should* work just fine. We're looking, but I wonder if simply deploying with a redundant js change will fix this (whether by re-minifying, or by flushing the CDN). The error in the second screenshot is unrelated.

Comment: I'm disappointed. This took far less than 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes hmmm, you're right; I'll revert and set a calendar reminder